# Change content of contentcontrol on mouse over (Freezable cannot be frozen)

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a viewbox with a contentcontrol in it.

This contentcontrol refers to a canvas resource. Now on mouseover I want to change the content of the contentcontrol to another canvas resource.

code:

```
<StackPanel x:Name="ExtraActionsPanel" Background="{DynamicResource DarkGrey}" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Height="38.5" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Viewbox x:Name="ActionIconBox1" Width="50" >
            <ContentControl Content="{DynamicResource action_message}"/>
        </Viewbox>
</StackPanel>
```

My app.xaml where the resources are :

```
<Canvas x:Key="action_message"  x:Shared="False" x:Name="action_message" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="38" Height="39.75" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="22" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource VeryLightBlue}" Data="F1 M 33,51L 36.4167,61.75L 24,51L 19,51L 19,22L 57,22L 57,51L 33,51 Z "/>
</Canvas>

<Canvas x:Key="action_message_focus" x:Shared="False" x:Name="action_message_focus" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
        <Path Width="38" Height="39.75" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="22" Stretch="Fill" Fill="{DynamicResource Blue}" Data="F1 M 33,51L 36.4167,61.75L 24,51L 19,51L 19,22L 57,22L 57,51L 33,51 Z "/>
</Canvas>
```

I've tried to use a Storyboard and a trigger to change the content on mouse over but that gives me a exception : Freezable cannot be frozen.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <Storyboard x:Key="OnMouseEnter1">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ContentControl.Content)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource action_message_focus}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</UserControl.Resources>
<UserControl.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="ActionIconBox1">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource OnMouseEnter1}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</UserControl.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried with the style triggers and it worked. Below is the style definition.

```
              <ContentControl>
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource action_message}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource action_message_focus}"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Freezable Objects Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms750509%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) page at MSDN:

> A Freezable can't be frozen if any of the following are true:
>
> •
> It has animated or data bound properties.
>
> •
> It has properties set by a dynamic resource. (See the Resources Overview for more information about dynamic resources.)
>
> •
> It contains Freezable sub-objects that can't be frozen.

I'm guessing that it applies to your `Canvas` control because you have a `Path` object inside it that itself can't be frozen because of the `DynaimcResource` it uses.